Why legend.position does not work in renderPlotly Rshiny
I want this bar chart to have legend at the top of the chart. When I ran the following code in Rstudio, the legend does appear at the top. However, when I put it in Rshiny via renderPlotly, legend is always on the right only. Anyone know why is this and how to fix this? This graph is shown in Rshiny as the photo attached.
 [![temp <- structure(list(Cow_No = c(292, 258, 18, 103, 147, 224, 157, 241, 
230, 260, 305, 204, 310, 215, 192, 231, 304, 134, 24, 84, 92, 
46, 77, 4, 67, 238, 217, 49, 284, 168), core_product = c("Short Gestation Length", 
"PS Daughter Proven", "Short Gestation Length", "Short Gestation Length", 
"Short Gestation Length", "PS Daughter Proven", "Short Gestation Length", 
"Short Gestation Length", "PS Forward Pack", "Nominated", "Short Gestation Length", 
"PS Daughter Proven", "PS Daughter Proven", "PS Forward Pack", 
"PS Daughter Proven", "PS Daughter Proven", "PS Forward Pack", 
"PS Daughter Proven", "Nominated", "Short Gestation Length", 
"Short Gestation Length", "Short Gestation Length", "PS Forward Pack", 
"Nominated", "Short Gestation Length", "Short Gestation Length", 
"Nominated", "Nominated", "Short Gestation Length", "Nominated"
), bw = c(-31.1, -26.5, 21.3, 23, 35.9, 58.2, 63.3, 79.5, 83.9, 
83.9, 88.6, 108.9, 118.6, 119.4, 119.5, 119.6, 122.9, 123.7, 
128.8, 147.1, 149.4, 149.6, 154.4, 160.6, 167.7, 172.6, 173.4, 
181.5, 182.6, 184.3), seq = 1:30), row.names = c(NA, -30L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
        
        allprod_chart <- ggplot(temp, aes(x=seq, y = bw, fill=core_product,label=Cow_No)) +
          geom_bar(stat="identity") +
          ggtitle("ABC") +
          scale_fill_manual(values=c( "PS Forward Pack" ="deepskyblue", "Short Gestation Length" ="brown",
                                      "Sire Proving Scheme" = "blue3", "PS Daughter Proven" = "darkblue",
                                      "Nominated"= "brown3",  "Sexed Semen"  = "darkgreen" ,
                                      "PS A2A2" = "lightblue", "Frozen Sexed"  = "lightgreen",
                                      "Unknown" = "grey"
                                      ))+
          theme_minimal() +
          theme( axis.ticks.x=element_blank()
                 ,axis.title = element_text( size = 14, face = "bold" )
                 , legend.position = "top"
                 , strip.text = element_text(size = 14, face = "bold")
                 , plot.title = element_text(size = 20)
          )
        
        print(allprod_chart)][1]][1]


I found a number of posts with similar issues:
How to change legend position in ggplotly in R
Theme(position.legend="none") doesn't work with coord_flip()
How to change legend position in ggplotly in R
Eventually, I found that legend.position always 'right' in ggplotly, except when legend.position = 'none' so it seems there is no way to fix my issue if I use ggplotly instead of ggplot. Please correct me if I am wrong
https://github.com/plotly/plotly.R/issues/1049
